# Quick to learn ORM for .NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, orm

I want to throw together a .net website as an interface to a subsystem I manage.

I'm planning to use ASP.net (on .net 2.0) because this is the shop's standard.

I would like to use an ORM because I was playing with Django a little bit ago and realize the time saver and code simplifier it was. I realize I may not get the time saving aspect because of the setup but I think it should make maintenance easier.

Can someone recommend a stable, very easy to learn/setup ORM product that works with ASP.NET 2.0. I prefer open source, but as long as the product is free it's fine.

Because learning something is dependent on the learner I want to share that I'm an experienced developer. I use a lot of languages and generally learn quickly with good material.

Comment: I guess there's no chance of using .NET 3.5 with LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework?

Comment: No, our production web servers don't have 3.5 nor does the company provide VS 2008.  I'm limited to 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend NHibernate. It is full featured, very mature and (in my experience) quite stable. Take a look at the [summer of nhibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com) screencasts (also free) and you'll have enough knowledge to get up and running in no time!

Comment: I understand the learning curve is steep. Otherwise, I'd be on this wagon.

Comment: It is not all that steep - sure, the more advanced stuff takes time but getting up and running connecting to a db and doing regular queries is easy. Also, think long term - for the sake of a few hours this is a great tool to have in your toolbelt...

Comment: I do see your point and since I prefer NHibernate (I'd also like to learn Hibernate [for Java]), it's probably worth the time investment even if the investment needs to be over the weekend... I'm looking in to this...  I'll check out the screencasts. Please feel free to post other useful quick-learn materials.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Castle Active Record](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html).

It's built ontop of NHibernate, which is a pretty popular one, but Castle's AR is faster to get off the ground with in my opinion.

I used it on my last ASP.NET project so can vouch for usefulness there. :)

Edit - Here's a quick link to "[Getting started](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/index.html)".

Comment: This is a possibility but it seems to lead me back to NHibernate. Thank you for the suggestion. I will certainly continue to look though the getting started materials.