# Way to coalesce/tokenize a SQL Command

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I would like to break a "SELECT" SQL statement into its logical components. i.e. I would like to create an object like "SelectSqlStatement" which has a property called "Table", "Where", "OrderBy", etc. The reason I want to do it is that I don't want to manipulate a string but rather manipulate an object and serialize it back to a string.

Before I write one for .NET, I was wondering if there was one available. I did a search but didn't see anything.

Comment: If you're bent on doing it yourself, I'd recommend using [StringTemplate](http://stringtemplate.org/) with its SQL grammars to facilitate the parsing and reconstruction. Bind its tokens to an object and you have a very ugly and heavy SQL builder.

Comment: definitely not bent on doing it myself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx)
- [Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/06/18/vb-entity-framework-samples-now-available-lisa-feigenbaum.aspx)
- [nHibernate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22768/Using-Nhibernate-in-VB-NET)

  - [nHibernate as the solution for .NET 2.0 ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009435/quick-to-learn-orm-for-net-2-0)

Just to name a few. What you are looking for is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

*All links are what I could quickly find for VB.

Comment: Hrmm, that does complicate things. However, I do believe that nHibernate (which admittedly has the hardest barrier to entry) can work with 2.0.

Comment: Editted my answer to include a previous SO question specifically for .NET 2.0 ORMs

Answer (score 5):

You can use the scriptdom parser of sql server for that.
Its in the Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll and give you an ast of TSqlFragment's that builds up the tsql query.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool initialQuotedIdentifiers = false;
    TSqlParser parser = new TSql110Parser(initialQuotedIdentifiers);

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@".\test.sql");
    IList<ParseError> errors;
    TSqlFragment fragment = parser.Parse(sr, out errors)

    //do stuff with the fragment

    //Generate tsql from the fragment
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
    Sql110ScriptGenerator scriptGen = new Sql110ScriptGenerator();
    scriptGen.GenerateScript(fragment, sw);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TopCoder offers a very powerful [SQL Parser](http://topcoder.com/home/blog/component/sql-parser-2/) component. I used it in a real project (also built for TopCoder) and it works very well. Its parser grammar is very complex, more than a thousand lines of code. Rebuilding it would likely turn into a costly effort.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're really looking for an ORM (for example nHibernate).

SQL grammar otherwise is fairly complicated. If you really do want to parse, then you need to search for the BNF grammar or roll your own BNF based on what's provided in Books Online. A quick search hasn't eluded an existing grammar for Microsoft's T-SQL, although they do exist for standard SQL. All the best!